# Error on sorting an paired integer ArrayList using comparater

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, pairing

I got an error while sorting an paired integer ArrayList i.e. cannot find symbol comparator in below code:

```java
Collections.sort(possibleHeights,new Comparater<Pair>(){
    public int compare(Pair p1,Pair p2)
    {
        return p1.getValue()-p2.getValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you imported java.util.Comparator?

Comment: Also, it is Comparator not Comparater

Comment: Also, what about the error?